# Phonegap build error for windows

Tags: phonegap-build

I am trying to create a build for windows using [here](https://build.phonegap.com) where as was following this same method till last week.

unfortunately today I am getting error as below,

[image]

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CLI if you are using Build.

Comment: You mean to say I have to uninstall node js and cordova which I installed separately ?

Comment: No. Please read the PhoneGap Build docs. You don't need node, or the CLI. That's the point of Build. But I'd keep node as it's useful for other things and one day you may want to use Ionic and Cordova or something like that.

Comment: Okay, will take a look at Document and will come back

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the plugin again

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration

Comment: I tried this I am getting a message that `Plugin "cordova-plugin-vibration" already installed on browser.`

Comment: After few try I understood that in my `config.xml` file cordova vibration version is 2.1.0 where as phonegap build is trying to install version 2.1.1. So I uninstalled local plugin vinbration but again it is showing 2.1.0 instead of 2.1.1, Any idea ?

Comment: Please paste you xml here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isue. I solved the problem that I had excluded all plugins from xml except on and then I tried to build. After every succesful build I include new plugin, then I came to the error.

You have wrong plugin for vibration in xour xml:

your plugin :

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
```

replace it with this:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" spec="0.3.13" source="pgb" />
```

Tell me if it works?

Regards, Ivan

Comment: In my case it looks like <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/> I changed npm to pbg also but no luck. Does `pgb` stands for Phonegap Build ?